# Improving horrible screen-on battery life

Tags: battery, battery-life, htc, 8.0-oreo

My HTC 10 is doing horribly when it comes to screen-on battery life after its update to Android 8.0. Average screen-on battery time is 1 hour and 15 minutes.

[image: GSam screen shot]

I've tried most I could: turning off animations (which were bugging anyway) and doing some screen brightness tricks. However this is not good, my phone used to be better before the 8.0 update.

Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you wiped the cache partition from recovery or performed a factory reset? After a major Android update it is not uncommon for a factory reset to be necessary.

Comment: Try what ace said.  But IME there is nothing your can do unless you can install the original factory OS onto the phone(which is only available for Pixels and unlocked phones depending on where you bought it).  You need an unlocked bootloader(different then unlocked carrier phone) and frankly the battery may even just be bad.

Answer (score 2):

Decrease your screen brightness, makes a huge difference. Unless you are outside in the sun, you won't need full brightness to see properly.